# More efficient way to list multiple variables that are similar in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables

I have some Javascript code that has Variables 1-9 that I feel could be written more efficiently? Using some sort of loop?

Here's a code snippet that I have which looks really sloppy and inefficient. Is there a better way to loop through the consecutive variables?

EDIT:

I ended up just using For loops to create separate arrays for each variable:

```js
      var num = []
      for (var i = 0; i < imgAr.length; ++i) {
        num[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * imgAr.length)
      }
      var img = []
      for (var j = 0; j < imgAr.length; ++j) {
        img[j] = imgAr[ num[j] ]
      }
      var imgStr = []
      for (var k = 0; k < imgAr.length; ++k) {
        imgStr[k] = '<img src="' + path + img[k] + '" alt = "">'
      }
```

```js
    var num1 = Math.floor( Math.random() * imgAr.length );
    var num2 = Math.floor( Math.random() * imgAr.length );
    var num3 = Math.floor( Math.random() * imgAr.length );
    var num4 = Math.floor( Math.random() * imgAr.length );
    var num5 = Math.floor( Math.random() * imgAr.length );
    var num6 = Math.floor( Math.random() * imgAr.length );
    var num7 = Math.floor( Math.random() * imgAr.length );
    var num8 = Math.floor( Math.random() * imgAr.length );
    var num9 = Math.floor( Math.random() * imgAr.length );
    var img1 = imgAr[ num1 ];
    var img2 = imgAr[ num2 ];
    var img3 = imgAr[ num3 ];
    var img4 = imgAr[ num4 ];
    var img5 = imgAr[ num5 ];
    var img6 = imgAr[ num6 ];
    var img7 = imgAr[ num7 ];
    var img8 = imgAr[ num8 ];
    var img9 = imgAr[ num9 ];
    var imgStr1 = '<img src="' + path + img1 + '" alt = "">';
    var imgStr2 = '<img src="' + path + img2 + '" alt = "">';
    var imgStr3 = '<img src="' + path + img3 + '" alt = "">';
    var imgStr4 = '<img src="' + path + img4 + '" alt = "">';
    var imgStr5 = '<img src="' + path + img5 + '" alt = "">';
    var imgStr6 = '<img src="' + path + img6 + '" alt = "">';
    var imgStr7 = '<img src="' + path + img7 + '" alt = "">';
    var imgStr8 = '<img src="' + path + img8+ '" alt = "">';
    var imgStr9 = '<img src="' + path + img9 + '" alt = "">';
```

Comment: you can write the function for similar activities and use return value

Comment: You mean `var arr = [];
    for (var i=0;i<9;i++) {
      arr.push('<img src="' + path + imgArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)] + '" alt = "">');
    }  `

Comment: Just reorder and use llops. Here a general recipe: Assuming that `A1` is 1st itteration of action A you reorder `A1,A2,A3.. B1,B2,B3.. C1,C2,C3..` to `A1, B1, C1, A2, B2, C2` then loop over itterations 'for (1-n){ Ax, Bx, Cx }'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use functions and arrays:

```
function randIndex(){
  return Math.floor( Math.random() * imgAr.length );
}

const nums = Array.from({length:9}, randIndex);

function getImage(index){
 return '<img src="' + path + imgAr[index] + '" alt = "">';
}

const imgs = nums.map( getImage );
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use simple cycle and an array. But instead of nine variables you get nine-length array as a result:

```
var imgStr = [];

for (i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
  var num = Math.floor( Math.random() * imgAr.length );

  imgStr[i] = '<img src="' + path + imgAr[num] + '" alt = "">';
}
```